# Failed to load main class from JAR file while running with spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am submitting the job using "spark-submit --master local --executor-memory 800m target/scala-2.10/finalproject_2.10-1.0.jar"

**And my sbt file is having below dependencies:**

```
name := "Projectx"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.4.0"
```

**My Code:**

```
object Projectx {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AirlineAnalysis")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
     sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")


    // HDFS
    val rawFlights= sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/Project/2008.csv")
       rawFlights.take(5) 
 val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("hdfs://localhost:9000/Project/2008.csv")
    df.take(5)
    df.printSchema()
    df.col("Year").cast("int")
   val df_1 = df.withColumnRenamed("Year","oldYear")
   val df_2 = df_1.withColumn("Year",df_1.col("oldYear").cast("int")).drop("oldYear")
  def convertColumn(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, name:String, newType:String) = {
  val df_1 = df.withColumnRenamed(name, "swap")
  df_1.withColumn(name, df_1.col("swap").cast(newType)).drop("swap")
}
  val df_3 = convertColumn(df_2, "ArrDelay", "int")
  val df_4 = convertColumn(df_2, "DepDelay", "int")

  val averageDelays = df_4.groupBy(df_4.col("FlightNum")).agg(avg(df_4.col("ArrDelay")), avg(df_4.col("DepDelay")))
  averageDelays.cache()
  averageDelays.show()
  averageDelays.orderBy("AVG(ArrDelay)").show()
averageDelays.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").save("hdfs://localhost:9000/Flight")
  sc.stop()
  }
    }
```

**The Error**

```
spark-submit --master local --executor-memory 800m target/scala-2.10/projectx_2.10-1.0.jar
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/home/hdadmin/target/scala-2.10/projectx_2.10-1.0.jar
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
```

Please help!

Answer (score 6):

Try adding:

```
--class "packageName.Projectx"
```

to the run command. (Where the 'packageName.' depends on your project structure, and may not be necessary.)

EDIT:
In response to your 2nd error (in the comments below), I believe you need this as well in your run command:

```
--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
```

Comment: I was able to run it with this spark-submit --class "finalproject" --master local --executor-memory 800m target/scala-2.10/finalproject_2.10-1.0.jar"

Comment: But i am getting this error now "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:77)"

Answer (score 1):

This works `spark-submit --class "finalproject" --master local --executor-memory 800m target/scala-2.10/finalproject_2.10-1.0.jar`

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add --class ,so it can't find the main class from the jar.

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html